# Run rspecs in parallel WITHOUT several processes

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I run several rspecs in parallel without launching several processes? More precisely, my requirement is that the `RSpec.configure` blocks should be run only once for the whole test suite. However, solutions such as `parallel_tests` seem to launch several processes and each process runs the `Rspec.configure` blocks.

The tests are not CPU intensive. Basically, an `RSpec.configure` block launches a bunch of machines on Amazon and then each tests runs commands on a subset of these machines and checks the output.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/bicarbon8/rspec-parallel, it might be what you want.

Comment: @NabeelAmjad Thanks, but it doesn't seem to support rspec 3.4. I'll see if it's usable nonetheless.

Comment: Hey, you can have a look at https://gist.github.com/flavorjones/108780 and maybe tweak it for your needs.

Comment: I would extract the `RSpec.configure` block to a separate script. Then wrap the test runner command in a way that it calls the script before calling `rspec`. Another way is to keep the AWS stuff in `RSpec.configure` but set an environment variable so that it only runs the first time. Like `if ENV["AWS_COMMANDS_HAVE_BEEN_RUN"]` or something.